# Regex error, nested tags

Tags: php, regex, nested, conditional-statements

I'm trying to code a simple template engine in PHP for my MVC framework.
I'm writing a method to handle if conditions in my template, using some special tags.

I wrote this code:

```
<?php
$text = '{% if var = val %}

{%if var1 = var1 %}
{% endif %}

{% endif %}

{%if var = val1 %}

{%if var1 = var1 %}
{% endif %}

{% endif %}';


function check_condition($text)
{
    /*
    1 - preg_match_all (get all conditions)
    2 - scroll all the conditions 
    2.1 - check if the condition is still present in the primary source
    2.2 - resolve the condition and get the text to print
    3 - replace the text in the primary source
    */

//1
if(preg_match_all('/{% if (.*) %}(.*){% endif %}/s', $text, $conditions))
{
    //2
    foreach($conditions as $condition)
    {
        //2.1
        if(preg_match('/'.$condition[0].'/', $text))
        {
            //2.2
            preg_match('/{% if (.*) %}/U', $condition[0], $data); 
            //check for and/or

            $data = str_ireplace('{% if ', '', $data);
            $data = str_ireplace(' %}', '', $data[0]);
            $data = explode(' = ', $data);

            if($data[0] == $data[1])
            {
                //3
                $text = str_ireplace($condition[0], 'some text'.$condition[0], $text);
            } else {
                //check for else

            }
        }
    }
}
return $text;
}

echo check_condition($text);
```

The **text var** contain an example of conditions, the function is not complete.

This regex:

```
if(preg_match_all('/{% if (.*) %}(.*){% endif %}/s', $text, $conditions))
```

Should get the entire condition block, in this case:

```
[0] => '{% if var = val %}

{%if var1 = var1 %}
{% endif %}

{% endif %}'
[1] => '{%if var1 = var1 %}
    {% endif %}'
[2] => '{%if var = val1 %}

{%if var1 = var1 %}
{% endif %}

{% endif %}'
[3] => '{%if var1 = var1 %}
{% endif %}'
```

But it returns a single block with the entire code (from the first {%if .. %} to the last {%endif%})

The problem is with the nested conditions, I think that the regex can't handle this.
Anyone have any ideas? How can I resolve this?
There is any other method that I can use?

Comment: Just a side note on readability. With instances like `2.1`, I like doing something like `if(!condition) continue;` so that you don't need to keep indenting every time you check a conditional.

Comment: it's greedy. use a lazy indicator `?` after the matching elements, inside groupings.

Answer (score 1):

Well `.*` matches all the symbols it can get its hands on.
Try using the "lazy" version by substituting `.*` with `.*?`. It should match the minimum possible characters to pass to the next part of the regular expression.

But this still wouldn't give you what you want I guess.
`start1 start2 end2 end1` will match on `start1-end2` even though it shouldn't. There should be some more checks between the `if` and `endif` that would account for other pairs contained within.

Comment: Yes, I think that using a regex is not the best way...
Do you know any alternatives?